# "Hello Word" Not Building in Kepler Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to compile Hello World program in eclipse KEPLER. But I am able to compile it. It is showing  error: 
 "make: *** [src/hello.o] Error 126 hello           C/C++ Problem"
In console error is :
 **/usr/bin/gcc: /usr/bin/gcc: cannot execute binary file**.
I have included below in the Includes (Path & Symbol):
**C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\3.4.4\include**,
**C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\3.4.4**,
**C:\cygwin\usr\include**,
**C:\cygwin\usr\include\w32api**,
**C:\cygwin\usr\local**,
I also added Cygwin bin and lib in Environment variables. But Still not working.

Please Guide me where I am going wrong, and what is missing. I formatted my laptop yesterday and all the previous eclipse setting went away. Before formatting, it was working fine. I was able to uild and run the programs.

Please Help

Comment: What is the result of `cygcheck -c`? Is `C:\cygwin\bin` in your PATH?

Comment: where can i check cygcheck -c? Yes, i have set my path variable as C:\cygwin\bin.

Comment: Please... someone reply... I need this to be done..I tried many ways to get it done..I think i am skipping/going wrong somewhere. I am not able to attach any screenshot. Please help me...

Comment: I got this done... but with MinGW... seemsas of there was some issue with cygwin.